# How do you access deleted questions?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

About a month ago, I wrote a question that was deemed as inappropriate for the site, so I deleted it. I would like to find it now so that I can post the question on another site for which it is more appropriate, but I can't find it. Where do I have to go in order to access my deleted questions, or are deleted questions removed after a period of time?

Comment: There is a deleted recent questions link at the bottom of your questions tab in your profile.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can view your recently deleted question by clicking the "view recently deleted questions"  link at the bottom of your questions page. Per  Shadow Wizard's comment, it appears that the history lasts for 60 days.

This should be yours: [View your recently deleted questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/2941352)

Comment: Okay, thank you. I found it on my profile page. I would vote your answer up if I had 15 reputation points, but since I can't do that, I am afraid you'll have to settle for the green check-mark that I will give you in 7 minutes since I am not allowed to do it now for some reason.

Comment: @DavidB Yeah, that 15 minute wait gets people all the time. Also, I'm told that you can also flag for moderator attention and ask them to pull it up if the question is no longer recent.

Comment: @JoshMein Looking through my older posts, I found this. Here's that upvote that I couldn't give you before.